# PHP array and Ajax response

Tags: php, ajax

I am currently trying to call a php script through Ajax so I can read it in my html file. I am using Json and Ajax to achieve this. I am having an issue with my php script where I can't get the information to format correctly when sending it over to the html. Here's my php:

```
$return_arr = array();
$fetch = mysqli_query("SELECT User_Id, First_Name, Last_Name FROM Users"); 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['User_Id'] = $row['User_Id'];
    $row_array['First_Name'] = $row['First_Name'];
    $row_array['Last_Name'] = $row['Last_Name'];
    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

I am getting the following type of response:

```
[{"User_Id":"6","First_Name":"Joe","Last_Name":"Shmo"},
{"User_Id":"17","First_Name":"Test","Last_Name":"Test"},
{"User_Id":"18","First_Name":"Test","Last_Name":"Test"},
{"User_Id":"19","First_Name":"Test","Last_Name":"Test"},
{"User_Id":"21","First_Name":"HI","Last_Name":"HI"}]
```

Now this causes me to have troubles while accessing in the html. I am trying to access it like:

```
data[0].User_Id
```

This gets undefined. I suspect the brackets are in the wrong places but can figure out how to switch them around.

Comment: Could you include the Javascript code you're using to fetch the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
<?php

header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');

echo json_encode( $return_arr );
```

Comment: Very interesting. That worked correctly. What does this do exactly?

Comment: It tells the client that you're sending JSON data back.

Comment: The response you pasted above is probably just one big string (i.e. the string returned by `json_encode`).  It looks like a JS object, but it isn't until you parse it into one.  Instead of setting the header correctly, you could have done `var dataJson = JSON.parse(data)` and converted the string response into a JS object.  Or told your AJAX library to expect JSON back.

Comment: It told your AJAX call that you were using JSON.
When you don't tell your JS what data type you're using, it'll try to look into the Content-type.
You can also simply write the datatype in your JS code. That's simpler to write and easier to understand.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for the responses!